# Inno Setup shorten file path string to fit FilenameLabel

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

On the `WizardForm.InstallingPage`, the `WizardForm.FilenameLabel` automatically truncates the string containing the file path, to include the drive letter at the beginning, followed by the maximum displayable path, truncating from the top level of the path, to fit the size of the label, so that the file name is always shown e.g. `C:\...\LongFilePathNameWithMultipleSubDirectories\Filename.ext`.

I have looked at the `Length`, `Pos`, `Copy` and `ExtractFileDrive` String Functions, but given that there are an almost infinite number path and file name possibilities, as the user can choose any installation path they wish, I am struggling to work out a way to show the maximum possible length of the path, without truncating the file name.

I think I need a function like `Pos` that returns the number of matches and the index for every `\` it finds, which would mean I could use `Length` between each index to determine where to `Copy` from, but I haven't been able to find any way of doing this.

Comment: So you want the max number of chars in a path before any `...` truncation? - thats a really weird thing to want - You are going to need to consider the specific font thats being used, download the inno source code & look at MinimizePathName() in cmnfunc.pas to see how it works with GetTextWidth().

Comment: I basically want to emulate what Inno Setup does for the `FilenameLabel` display when extracting files. So if `C:\First Folder\Second Folder\Third Folder\Filename.ext` is too long to fit `FilenameLabel`, then it would truncate as follows `C:\...\Second Folder\Third Folder\Filename.ext` or `C:\...\Third Folder\Filename.ext` as appropriate in order to fit, but also display the maximum amount of the path that is possible.

Comment: As in http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_minimizepathname ?

Comment: That is exactly the function I needed. I don't know how I missed it in the documentation. If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MinimizePathName()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_minimizepathname) function is available to scripting, it takes a string & a font and returns a reformatted string that will fit in a given number of pixels in the given font.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MinimizePathName` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_minimizepathname).

Something like this:

```pascal
YourLabelControl.Caption :=
   MinimizePathName(
     'C:\First Folder\Second Folder\Third Folder\Filename.ext',
     YourLabelControl.Font, YourLabelControl.Width);
```

(untested)